# Convert typed array to Integer array in android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to get the index by value in android. i am having typed array. I want to get the index by it's value. I come to know that I can get the index by the following code. `Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(value)`. I am using typed array. That is premitive type. So that I am getting only -1. So I want to change the the Typed array to Integer type. Can any one give me idea to solve my issue. I am trying the following.

```
TypedArray arrTest = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.test_array);

Integer value = arrDisplayBrightness.getInteger(5,0);
int index =  Arrays.asList(arrTest).indexOf(value);
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(arrTest).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()).indexOf(value)`, or simply do a basic `for` loop.

Comment: @Jai.. Yes. Right now I am using for loop. And you solution is also not working for TypedArray. Is there any other way to resolve?

Comment: Have you tried to use ```getInt(int index, int defValue)```  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getInt(int,%20int)  ?

Comment: @vasile.. This will return the value. Not index.